# Does pattern matching create a function?

Tags: scala

The `List.sortWith` method according to [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List): has signature

```
def sortWith(lt: (A, A) ⇒ Boolean): List[A]
```

Now for a list of strings we can do:

```
myList.sortWith((_,_) match { case(s1: String, s2: String) => s1.compareTo(s2)}
```

i.e use pattern matching when scala is saying it wants a function type.

In this case can we therefore say that

```
(_,_) match { case(s1: String, s2: String) => s1.compareTo(s2)
```

is a function application of the following function type `(A, A) ⇒ Boolean`?

Comment: You could write it as a partial function: `val f:(String, String) => Boolean = { case (s1, s2) => (s1 compareTo s2) > 0 }`

Answer (score 2):

Note that `compareTo` returns an Integer. If you want to comply with the signature `(A, A) ⇒ Boolean`, for alphabetical ascending order, you can use `<`.

All three of these anonymous functions will sort a `List`:

```
myList.sortWith(_ < _)
myList.sortWith { case(a, b) => a < b }
myList.sortWith( (_, _) match { case (a, b) => a < b} )
```